# ODBC Call failure from Microsoft Access to PostgreSQL -Client Encoding Mismatch

Tags: postgresql, odbc, ms-access-2007, datasource

i tried to create a linked table from `Microsoft Access (2007)` to `PostgreSQL` (9.0) in `Windows 7`. When I tried to linked table as follows:

1)Select link to the data source by creating a linked table

2)Machine Data Source in '`Selectr Data Source`' pop up.

3)Select the PostgreSQL DB visible which ends in error:

```
ODBC call failed
Clientencoding mismatch(#214).
```

Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

I used [Google](http://www.google.com) to find [this](http://tadek.pietraszek.org/blog/2005/12/02/postgresql81-client-encoding-mismatch-with-odbc/).

> It seems that there is some problem with PostgreSQL 8.1 and the encoding names: see this post or google. It looks that UTF8 used by default with the new Postgres is not compatible with old ODBC drivers. I am not sure where the problem really is, but a quick fix is to change default encoding for the user connecting to the database:
>
> `alter user <user> SET client_encoding to LATIN1;`